# Batch inserts with Perl's DBI

Tags: perl, postgresql

I'm trying to do a batch insert of rows of data into a postgres database.

I have the data populated in an array ref, I think. It was fetched using a perl script from a space delimited file using the [`Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol`module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol). The code to fetch the data is

```
 $ss = new Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol($xlsFileName) ||
 die "Could not open '$xlsFileName': $!";
 $ss->setColumns(@columnHeadings);

 my @array;

 my $row = 0;
 while (my $data = $ss->getNextRow())
 {
     $row++;

     push @array, "@$data";
 }
```

Below is the content of the array ref.

```
Cristan McX  123 W State Street North Aurora IL
William Sch  123 South Third St #367 Geneva IL
Kellie xxx  123 South East St. Gardner IL
John xx  321 Princeton Ct. Frankfort IL
Peter xxxxxxx  123 N Myrtle Avenue Elmhurst IL
Izabella xxx  321 S 3rd St. #367 Geneva IL
```

The Perl DBI code I'm using to do the inserts is:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=greenthumb;host=localhost;    port=5432","","", {'RaiseError' => 1});

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO testtable (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' );

foreach(@array) { $sth->execute( @{$_} ); }
$sth->finish;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Can't use string ("FirstName LastName BusinessName "...) as an ARRAY ref   while "strict refs" in use at ./f.pl line 38.
```

Comment: `$_` is not an array, it is a string. You'll likely want to `split` it first.

Comment: Additionally, if it truly is space separated, how are you going to differenciate the fields when they contain space, i.e. `123 W State Street North`?

Comment: You also need the keyword `VALUES` before your list of values: `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ...`. It seems like you probably want to do your inserts in the loop that iterates over the spreadsheet contents rather than stringifying and de-stringifying.

Comment: `$_` is not an arrayref, it is a string. But `$data` was an arrayref. You could have just said `push @array, $data`.

Answer (score 3):

Not a general DBI solution, but since you are using PostgreSQL, you can also use "COPY" for efficient bulk inserts, adding each row as you grab it from the spreadsheet:

```
...
$dbh->do("COPY testtable FROM STDIN");
while ( my $data = $ss->getNextRow ) {
    $dbh->pg_putcopydata(join("\t", @$data) . "\n");
}
$dbh->pg_putcopyend();
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the advice you have received in comments and adding a few corrections of my own, your program should look something like this. I've not been able to test it as I'm posting from a tablet

There's no need to read the whole spreadsheet into memory -- simply insert the data into the database table as you read it from the XLS file

Clearly you will have to replace the column names with real-world values. If you simply want all of the data in the spreadsheet then you should use [`Spreadsheet::BasicRead`](http://search.cpan.org/~gng/Spreadsheet-BasicRead-1.11/BasicRead.pm)

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;
use DBD::Pg;
use Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol;

use constant XLS_FILE => 'myfile.xls';

my $dbh    = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Pg:dbname=greenthumb;host=localhost;port=5432', '', '', { RaiseError => 1 } );
my $insert = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' );

my $ss = Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol->new(
    fileName      => XLS_FILE,
    columns       => [ qw/ FirstName LastName BusinessName col4name col5name col6name / ],
    skipHeadings  => 1,
    skipBlankRows => 1,
) or die sprintf "Could not open '%s': %s", XLS_FILE, $!;

while ( my $data = $ss->getNextRow ) {
    $insert->execute(@$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an array reference from `$ss->getNextRow`, but you dereference it and convert the array into a string when pushing it on to the array.

```
push @array, "@$data";
```

(The `@$data` dereferences the referenced array and `"..."` converts the dereferenced array into a string.)

If you just pushed the array reference that you have, then everything would work.

```
push @array, $data;
```

But I like [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770113/7231) as it eliminates the need for the intermediate `@array` and processes the spreadsheet a row at a line.